# What is the Booklet behind the case of BioShock 2?

Tags: bioshock-2

I saw a shrink-wrapped, retail copy of BioShock 2 for PC at the store recently and there appeared to be some sort of booklet in the shrink-wrap behind the case.

What is that booklet? Is it the manual? Is it some sort of extra art booklet? Why is it not inside the case?

**Update**:
I just got a copy of BioShock 2 from eBay and it did not have such a booklet. The manual that came inside the case had a different backside altogether (it was plain with the logos, copyrights, URLs, and the key printed on it). However the back of the case (i.e., the art work) matches the unidentified booklet. Now I am even more curious about what this booklet could be.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Synetech, gee, great. Removing the `manual` tag got the attention of a hit-and-run-down-voter. \*sigh\*

Comment: For the record, I never found out for sure. I considered asking the clerk at the store to open it, but I never saw this again at WalMart and Zellers no longer exists. I ended up getting a used copy from an American seller on eBay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Canada, where I live, games must include bilingual instructions.  My copy of BioShock included a French manual that was attached to the outside of the package, since the two manuals were too thick to fit inside the PS3 case.

Comment: The ones I saw (identical at Wal-Mart and Zellers) had an English booklet on the back. I suppose they could have a French one inside; though usually both languages are together in the same manual (though to be fair, I don’t know how thick the BioShock2 manual is yet).

Comment: @Synetechinc. I am almost positive it is another copy of the instructions - I've seen a lot of games for PC and consoles that have two manuals - one french, one english.

Comment: Then I guess the French one would be inside because the one on the back is English. It’s just that my copy of BioShock 1 had a single dual-language manual and the one on the back of BioShock 2 isn’t exactly too thick. I can’t fathom a reason for doing it this way.